# Play-Framework 2.3.x: Unable to send emails using plugin "play-mailer"

Tags: scala, email, reactive-programming, playframework-2.3

I am using `play-framework 2.3.x` and `scala 2.11.4`. When integrate `play-mailer` for sending and emails from my application, there is nothing happen. In the logs there are no exception produces and no return values are available. Following is email properties:

```
smtp.host = "smtp.gmail.com" 
smtp.port = 25 
smtp.user = "n****@gmail.com" 
smtp.password = "*******"
smtp.debug = true 
smtp.mock = true
```

My Scala Code:

```
Future{
  var subject = "Invitation email";
  var from = "h****@gmail.com";
  var to = userList.map { user => user.email }.seq;
  var email: Email = new Email(subject, from, to);
  CustomUtility.sendEmail(email)
}
```

I need to send my all emails to `async` task. My `CustomUtility` method :

```
def sendEmail(email: Email){
 var message = MailerPlugin.send(email);
 println("MESSAGE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : "+message);
}
```

**Update**

The major problem is that, i am not receiving an emails

Comment: can you show me the link where you found the sample code for sending email with attached file.

Comment: @Vicky 2 sorry, i have not seen any example like that. Please find test case at `github` of `play-mailer`. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to make this changes from the sample code play mailer

firts add the file /conf/play.plugins with the content:

```
1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Second you configuration in application.conf must be:

```
smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.tls=true
smtp.user="yourgmailuser@gmail.com"
smtp.password="yourpasswor"
```

and the controller sending your code this, yo do need to use futures as I follow the example in the [github repository](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer)

```
package controllers


import models.SignUpValidation
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, Json}
import play.api.mvc._


import java.io.File

import play.api.libs.mailer._
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.Play.current


object Application extends Controller {

  def send = Action {

val email:Email = Email(
  "Simple email",
  "Mister FROM <from@email.com>",
  Seq("Miss TO <to@email.com>"),
  attachments = Seq(
    AttachmentFile("favicon.png", new File(current.classloader.getResource("public/images/favicon.png").getPath)),
    AttachmentData("data.txt", "data".getBytes, "text/plain", Some("Simple data"), Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))
  ),
  bodyText = Some("A text message"),
  bodyHtml = Some("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message</p></body></html>")
)

val id = MailerPlugin.send(email)

Ok(s"Email $id sent!")
  }


}
```

You can use this code inside an asyn task like [async](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync)

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

val futureInt: Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.Future {
  sendMail()
}
```

for an asyncronus methos in a controller

```
def sendWithFuture = Action.async {


      val futureString = scala.concurrent.Future {

        val email:Email = Email(
          "Simple email",
          "Mister FROM <anquegi@email.com>",
          Seq("Miss TO <antonio.querol@cuaqea.com>"),
          attachments = Seq(
            AttachmentFile("favicon.png", new File(current.classloader.getResource("public/images/favicon.png").getPath)),
            AttachmentData("data.txt", "data".getBytes, "text/plain", Some("Simple data"), Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))
          ),
          bodyText = Some("A text message"),
          bodyHtml = Some("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message</p></body></html>")
        )

        MailerPlugin.send(email)


      }
      futureString.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))



  }
```

do not forget to add this import

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

If you want to use scala Futures in your action I recommend that use this code

imports:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
```

the method is:

```
def SendUsingScalaFutures = Action {

//Your code

val userList:List[User] = List(
  new User("email1"), new User("email2"))

val task = Future {
  var subject = "Invitation email";
  var from = "anquegi@gmail.com";
  var to = userList.map { user => user.email }.seq;

  var email: Email = new Email(subject, from, to);
  CustomUtility.sendEmail(email)// this will be better to return a String

}

// whenever the task completes, execute this code
task.onComplete {
  case Success(value) => println(s"MESSAGE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> :  ${value}" )
  case Failure(e) => println(s"D'oh! The task failed: ${e.getMessage}")
}



//Other code

Ok("Finish")



 }
```

and your CustomUtility

package controllers

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import play.api.Play.current


/**
 * Created by anquegi on 13/05/15.
 */
object CustomUtility {
  def sendEmail(email: Email): Unit =  {
    val message = MailerPlugin.send(email);
    message
  }

}
```

and my user class just for the sample

```
package models

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 13/05/15.
 */
case class User(email:String) {

}
```

I hope that your user class and user list works with your code if not please write them. I hope this works. I always recommend this entry in Alvin Alexander Blog for using futures: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-future-semantics

Comment: Hello @anquegi, this is still not work for me. This code is same as sample code. I don't want to create different `Action` for sending emails. In My action i read the file and create the list of user email for send the emails to user. You solutions is not work.

Comment: Ok i will make an edit an add the future onsunccess and on Failure methods

Comment: I hope that finally is what you want.

Comment: thanks @anquegi for your help, but the another problem is that, i am not receiving the emails.

Comment: I make an edit and the last code works did you follow all the steps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77701/discussion-between-anquegi-and-harmeet-singh-taara).

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara I make an edit and the last code works did you follow all the steps? do you use "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0"?

Comment: Hey @anquegi, this is work, when i delete configuration properties and again paste the properties. This is worked

Comment: It was nice to help you, I also learned a lot, Thanks for vote up!