# How to send email with attached file in scala and play framework (2.3.9) using activator?

Tags: scala, email-attachments, playframework-2.3

Well, i am completely new to Scala and Play framework. i saw many examples for sending mail with attached files in scala, i too followed them, Since i am using activator for my project i can't find play.plugin under conf in project instead i found only application.conf. Can anyone please give me a complete document or any link with complete reference standards step by step to learn them for mailer plugin. Advance thanks friends. Please complete reference, since i am in a hurry please help me guys.

Below links I refered:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765364/send-email-with-java-and-play-framework-2-2-2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492858/sending-emails-in-playframework-2-0
https://gist.github.com/mariussoutier/3436111
https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208339/play-framework-2-3-x-unable-to-send-emails-using-plugin-play-mailer
```

Please give me a link with sample code for complete understanding or any document of yours

I tried with [playframework play-mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) but I am getting some errors like,

```
[error] object inject is not a member of package javax
[error] import javax.inject.Inject
[error]              ^
[error] object MailerClient is not a member of package play.libs.mailer
[error] import play.libs.mailer.MailerClient;
[error]        ^
[error] not found: type MailerClient
[error] class MyComponent @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient)
[error]                                            ^
[error] not found: type Inject
[error] class MyComponent @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient)
[error]                    ^
[error] object play.libs.mailer.Email is not a value
[error]   val email = Email(
[error]               ^
[error] not found: value attachments
[error]     attachments = Seq(
[error]     ^
[error] not found: value bodyText
[error]     bodyText = Some("A text message"),
[error]     ^
[error] not found: value bodyHtml
[error]     bodyHtml = Some(s"""<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message   with cid < img src="cid:$cid"></p></body></html>""")
[error]     ^
[error] not found: value mailerClient
[error]   mailerClient.send(email)
```

Comment: i am too facing the same one, please if u get any complete reference update me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the plugin for Play 2.4.x whereas your application is based on Play 2.3.x.

As written in the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) of the plugin :

> For Play 2.3.x please read the [README on the 2.x branch](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/2.x/README.md#setup).

You can't use `@Inject`. Sample code from the link above in Scala :

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._

val email = Email(
  "Simple email",
  "Mister FROM <from@email.com>",
  Seq("Miss TO <to@email.com>"),
  // adds attachment
  attachments = Seq(
    AttachmentFile("attachment.pdf", new File("/some/path/attachment.pdf")),
    // adds inline attachment from byte array
    AttachmentData("data.txt", "data".getBytes, "text/plain", Some("Simple data"), Some(EmailAttachment.INLINE))
  ),
  // sends text, HTML or both...
  bodyText = Some("A text message"),
  bodyHtml = Some("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message</p></body></html>")
)
MailerPlugin.send(email)
```

You have everything you need to start sending emails.

**EDIT for `play.plugins`**

You need to create the file `conf/play.plugins` yourself and put this inside :

```
1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Comment: i can't find play.plugins in conf package

Comment: i keep on getting this error not found: type File c i am importing the wrong File class

Comment: Atlast i cleared all the error but while running the app i am getting Internal server error - java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Comment: I edited my answer for `play.plugins`. Regarding your other errors try an `activator clean compile` to clean everything.

Comment: thanks man, i solved it through some links. Thanks man for spending some time for me.